# Top of screen application menu bar on every monitor in multiple display

Tags: display, screen

I have a two monitor setup but the top of the screen application menu bar appears only on one (main) monitor.  I would like it to appear on both so that I don't have to travel with my mouse from the other to the main monitor to use it.  Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 2):

For now, use [SecondBar](http://blog.boastr.net). In Mavericks, this feature will be built into the OS.